# how to speed up a video sequence in blender 2.8?

Tags: edit-mode, video-sequence-editor, video

How to speed up a sequence using the video editor in blender 2.8? All tutorials I find online use older versions of blender.

Comment: Did you try that in the newer versions? What is it that is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done the same way it was done in previous versions.

Select the video strip you want to change, add an Effect > Speed Control strip and multiply the speed to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Speeding up the video *framerate* (which is what I believe you mean by video speed) can be done the same way in 2.8 as it can be in 2.79 and before. In the render settings, switch the default 24 FPS to whatever is faster than that. It should speed up the video speed.

Comment: No, I meant selecting a sequence in the timeline and make it run 2x faster for example. Only a particular sequence, not the entire video.