# How can I edit the speed of a single part of an animation?

Tags: animation, frame-rate

I would like to speed up one part of my animation, without changing the overall speed. How can I do this?

Comment: you could do it with some keyframe scaling, you could also do it in the video sequencer. You can't use the Time Stretching as it would affect the whole animation

Comment: .. "one part of anim" you mean specific object in a scene ... or to change speed of rendered result in time? Probably duplication ... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164328/ or here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1053

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As my previous speakers said, "one part of my animation" is very vague... is a part some object(s) in the scene or do you mean a certain frame range of the complete animation? Also people refer to a simulation as animation as well since you can get an animated result, or otherwise it could be a keyframed animation. Or both. So to tell you how you can achieve your goal it would be really helpful if you could specify what you are trying to do.